# How can i make my v-menu goes up right with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I'm new in frontend and im trying to move my v-menu top right but without succed. So here is a little more about problem:

My `App.vue`

```
<v-content>
  <v-container grid-list-sm>
    <router-view />
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs4 sm4 offset-sm4>
        <v-card height="200px">
          <v-card-title class="blue white--text">
            <span class="headline">Menu</span>

            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-menu bottom left>
              <v-btn slot="activator" dark icon>
                <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
              </v-btn>

              <v-list>
                <v-list-tile v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" @click="">
                  <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>Lorem Ipsum</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

What I expect:

[image]

Comment: Please reference the docs by https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid

Comment: It help me a lot thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!